# How to make header clickable

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm thinking how my header **about** and **friends** can be clickable. I just add `class = block` so it can be clickable and to check if it's working using `alert` function. But it won't work.

```
<script>

$(document).on("click", "#about", function ()
{
    alert('Hi');
});

</script>
```

**Header**

```
<div class = "col-lg-6">
    <div class = "panel panel-default" style = "height: 300px;">
        <div class = "panel-heading" style = "height: 50px;">
            <div class="col-xs-3"><h3 class="panel-title" style = "padding-top: 7.5px;"><a class = "block" id = "about">About</a></h3></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"><h3 class="panel-title" style = "padding-top: 7.5px;"><a class = "block">Friends</a></h3></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well are you attaching the event before the element is rendered to the page?

Comment: it is working just fine https://jsfiddle.net/mp6oquxz/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
// wait for page to load
    $("a#about").click( function (){ 
      // do your clicked stuff here
      alert('Hi'); 
    })
});
```

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

Update: working example https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5740/

You will get alert only when you click on About text, not anywhere else

Comment: What I want to do If I click the header `about` it will prompt the alert.

Comment: You want to get alert when you click on  the link About?

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm just using alert to check if its clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#about').on("click", function() {
    alert('Hi');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6" id="about">
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 300px;">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="height: 50px;">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="padding-top: 7.5px;"><a class = "block" id = "about">About</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="padding-top: 7.5px;"><a class = "block">Friends</a></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How my header that has `id = "about"` can be clickable?

Comment: @Francisunoxx so use `$('#about')` instead of `$('.header')`

Comment: Bro if I click any part of the panel it still prompting the alert.